# Draw small sample from large set with discrete distribution efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random, probability

I have two lists, both the same size, let's call them `elements` and `weights`. I want to **choose one** element of the `elements` list **with discrete probability distribution** given by `weights`. `weight[i]` corresponds to the probability of choosing `elements[i]`. `elements` never changes, but after every sample taken, `weights` changes (only the values, not the size).

I need an **efficient** way to do this with **large** lists.

I have an implementation in Python with `numpy.random.choice(elements, p=weights)` but taking a sample of size `k` from a set of size `n` where `k << n` is extremely inefficient. An implementation in any language is welcome, but I am working primarily in Python.

(This is used in a social network simulation with *networkx*. I have a weighted graph and a node `i` and I want to choose a node `j` from `i`'s neighbors where the probability for each node is proportional to the weight of the edge between `i` and the given node. If I set the probability to 0 for non-neighbors, I don't have to generate the list of neighbors every time, I just need a list of all nodes.)

It will be used like this:

```
elements = [...]
weights = [...]

for(...):
    element = sample(elements, weights)
    *Some calculation with element and changing the values of weights*
```

Comment: Weights are not normalized, right?

Comment: By default no. I normalized them with `sum()` followed by a list comprehension.

Comment: and a lot of them are zeros, right?

Answer (score 1):

@MarkBorgerding's approach is good but can be improved:

```
W = weights.cumsum()
W.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, W[-1], nsamples))
```

Also, it in the end depends on actual numbers, but instead of zeroing the probabilities of non neighbors it may well be more efficient to remove those probabilities; see Timings Part 2 below.

Timings:

`1000000` options, single sample:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> weights = np.random.random(1000000)
>>> 
>>> timeit("np.random.choice(1000000, 1, p=weights/weights.sum())", **kwds)
1.606048938119784
>>> timeit("W = weights.cumsum(); W/=W[-1]; (np.random.uniform()<W).argmax()", **kwds)
0.6634919850621372
>>> timeit("W = weights.cumsum(); W.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, W[-1]))", **kwds)
0.30993065400980413
```

`1000000` options, `10` samples:

```
>>> timeit("np.random.choice(1000000, 10, p=weights/weights.sum())", **kwds)
1.606177378911525
>>> timeit("W = weights.cumsum(); W/=W[-1]; (np.random.uniform(0, 1, (10, 1))<W).argmax(axis=1)", **kwds)
1.4421172500588
>>> timeit("W = weights.cumsum(); W.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, W[-1], 10))", **kwds)
0.3154504559934139
```

Timings part 2:

```
# assume we connect to 10% of the nodes
>>> neighbors = np.random.random(1000000) < 0.1
>>> 
# zeroing non connected weights
>>> timeit("W = np.where(neighbors, weights, 0).cumsum(); W.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, W[-1], 10))", **kwds)
0.553992060944438
# outright removing them
>>> timeit("nbidx, = np.where(neighbors); W = weights[nbidx].cumsum(); nbidx[W.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, W[-1], 10))]", **kwds)
0.32569816312752664
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like the following.  Use `cumsum` to form the weights into a cumulative distribution function and then sample from the inverse cdf.

```
wcs = weights.cumsum()
wcs = wcs / wcs[-1] # non-decreasing in (0:1]
u = np.random.uniform()
chosen = weights[(u < wcs).argmax()]  # the first index above u
```